# While loop removes unexpected number of elements from the python list

Tags: python, list, recursion, while-loop

I was trying to solve the classic coin change problem with the aim of getting all the possible coin combinations which can be changed for a given value of money. Although dynamic programming will be most suitable for this, I am using recursions just to develop my understanding. I am trying to keep a record of the function's position in the recursion tree by continuously appending a list. However, I also need to remove elements from list when function travels from one brach to other. For this purpose, I have used while loop in the code, but instead of just the last two elements from the list, it is removing three elements. Any clarifications would be appreciated -

```
masterlst = []
lst =[]

def MakeTree (n, coins):
    d = len(coins)
    for item in coins:
        print(item)
        lst.append(item)
        print(lst)
        m = n - item
        print(m)
        if m > 0:
            MakeTree(m,coins)
        if m == 0:
            global masterlst
            masterlst.append(lst[:])
            print(masterlst)
        while lst[-1] == max(coins):
            del lst[-1]
            print(lst)
        del lst[-1]
        print(lst)
        print('Done!')

output = MakeTree(6, (1,3,4))
print(output)
```

Terminal output is shown below -

```
[1]
5
1
[1, 1]
4
1
[1, 1, 1]
3
1
[1, 1, 1, 1]
2
1
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1
1
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
0
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Done!
3
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3]
-2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Done!
4
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4]
-3
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
Done!
[1, 1, 1]
Done!
```

As shown above, after printing -3 (6th line from bottom), I am expecting only

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
Done!
```

But program is going one step extra and producing

```
[1, 1, 1]
Done!
```

as well, which is not desired. I want to remove last two elements form the list as long as the last element is equal to `max(coins)` and remove only one otherwise.
I am new to python, so any other syntax improvement suggestion will also be helpful.

Comment: When I run your code, the output is different:  no list ever has anything but 1s.  Did you show us an older version?

Comment: Side hint: you don't need either `global` here.  You only need global if you're assigning a new value to the name.  You're just using the existing value.

Comment: Yes Tim, first few iterations will generate 1s as shown in the picture I attached.

Comment: What I mean is, I ran YOUR EXACT CODE and the result does not match the results in the picture you posted.  The script runs to termination, and I never see "[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3]".  That code did not produce that result.

Comment: Get out of the habit of doing `for i in range(len(list)):` Use `for item in list:`

Comment: What's the point of a `for` loop that has an unconditional `break` statement at the end of the body? It will never repeat.

Comment: Please show the output [as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Thanks.

Comment: Barmer, you are absolutely right. I did it just for troubleshooting.

Comment: Hey Tim, sorry for the confusion. Please try it now.